# Back-Up technology aside from EHD, SDcards, and USBdrives

Tags: storage

Is there another back-up modality (like some sort of disc) aside from SD cards, USB drives and EHD that can store large files ( over 4GB sizes), audio-visual,and pictures which has both longevity and has less risk of loss or  deletions from accidental internal malware, electromagnetic issues and the like; and that is not cloud based to third party ownership?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard DVD discs hold around 4.7 gigabytes apiece, and blue ray discs hold 25 gigabytes per layer (with two, three, and four layer discs available). Certain types (BD-RE) can be written to several times, whereas others (BD-R) are only writeable once.

One could use a blue-ray burner and blue ray discs to back up your data.

I would add a warning though: While optical means such as dvds and blue-ray discs might be less susceptible to electromagnetic energy than some other methods of storage, they may be more susceptible to light based damage.

Sources: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blu-ray#Competition_from_HD_DVD

Comment: Thank you for your comment; it is most helpful, and probably the direction that serves my archival needs.

Answer (score 1):

You could always go with LTO tapes. They a long life if you store them correctly. LTO 6 can hold 2.5 TB. Most large companies use them for backup and archive.

Answer (score 0):

You never stipulated if the data needed to be online all the time but the only media I know of to date is Blu-Ray media (BD-R) which store data at up to 50GB per disc, however the 25GB disc is more common and cost effective as of this posting.

Comment: Thank you. This archival option is the way to go for my basic needs.

Comment: Also for the novice, here is a link that helped me understand how it works! http://www.mediasupply.com/bluray.html

Answer (score 0):

I recommend setting up a 4-bay NAS (Synology DS414j or similar. Checkout DS3615xs for bigger.) and using a backup software to manage a full/incremental backup strategy.

I really like Synology for NAS products. I've worked with the large enterprise rack versions as well as the home line of products. All of their stuff works off the same OS (DSM), and is very user friendly. I've found them to be much better than QNAP products.

One thing I appreciate about Synology is the Synology Hybrid Raid feature. It's basically RAID5/6 (SHR1/SHR2) that allows you to upgrade the disks in your appliance simply by replacing each disk one at a time and letting it rebuild in between.

If you go this route, use either RAID5, which will allow for one disk to fail, or SHA1/2, which will allow for either 1 or 2 disks to fail, respectively.

A note on NAS appliance location. If you go this way, I suggest putting the NAS in a location that can be easily accessed in the event of a disaster. This way you can pick it up on the way out of the house. Ideally, run a conduit to a detached structure and set it up there. I have seen people build 'NAS Houses' on their property. Like a dog house, but for your NAS.

Here's a list of free backup software that may work for you. I suggest Comodo. I trust the company, and their free tier software offers full backup, incremental and differential as well as Shadow Copy. Encryption also.

https://backup.comodo.com/backup-features.php
http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-hard-drive-backup-program.htm

And a RAID calculator to help you envision your solution once it's built out.

https://www.synology.com/en-us/support/RAID_calculator

Comment: Thank you for your thorough comments. Appreciate your time put in to answer this.